# Sort Numbers spreadsheet by how many times a value appears in a column

Tags: numbers

[image: My spreadsheet]

From this image you can see I've sorted the table by column G alphabetically, but what I would like to do is isolate the rows that only have one instance of the value in the G column. Most have multiple but as you can see with the pink dots some only have 1.

Is there a way to order by the amount of times a value occurs on a column?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the frequency function in numbers.  https://help.apple.com/functions/mac/9.1/

Comment: Add a helper column and count how many times each appears, then sort by that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To isolate the rows that only have one instance of a value in the G column, use this method to simulate a pivot table. The columns of the table must have one row of headings.

1. Add a new column to the table.
2. Enter `IF(COUNTIF(G$1:G1,G2)=0,COUNTIF(G,G2),"")`
   in the second row of the new column and autocopy down to fill the column.
3. Select the new column and filter for values equal to 1.

Here's an example. The new column is `Count`.

[image: table with Count column]

Select the `Count` column and filter for values equal to 1.

[image: filtered table]